# failed to create receiver object from assembly

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-enterprise, feature-receiver

I have created two features and I want both use same receiver class so I created a class `MyFeatureReceiver` (somewhere in project `SP/MyRecievers/`) which implements `SPFeatureReceiver` and has an attribute [Guid("1F6B71C6-5AC2-4D02-87D5-7C3729CE6E3B")].

I have modified the properties of my two features as following:

```
Scope="Web" 
ReceiverClass="$SharePoint.Type.1F6B71C6-5AC2-4D02-87D5-7C3729CE6E3B.FullName$"
ReceiverAssembly="$SharePoint.Project.AssemblyFullName$"
```

I use PowerShell to deploy .wsp file which I have checked in CA and it is ok. but when I create site collection and its root web, it generates:

> Failed to create receiver object from assembly ...

I have another project which has used same principle and works fine, in that project when I go to the Features and choose their manifest the `$SharePoint.Type.1F6B71C6-5AC2-4D02-87D5-7C3729CE6E3B.FullName$` has been replaced with the namespace + the class name but in my project it has not been replaced and I think it is the problem. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

If your class is:

- in the same project
- inherits from SPFeatureReceiver
- is public
- has the right [Guid(xxx)] attribute

then it should work, but I would consider it a bad practice. A better solution woulc be to have two destinct feature receivers calling common functions, then if at some point you need to differentiate (could be in regards to FeatureUpgrading), then it'll be easier.